# How does dplyr resolves the queries with the same values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contain four columns and what i am interested is to select the best "Query_id" based on minimum "evalue"

Here is how my dataframe looks like:

```
  Query_id        Subject_id percent_identity  evalue 
1    35538      contig404347              100 4.6e+00 
2    35538 GeneScaffold_1991              100 4.6e+00 
3    35539 GeneScaffold_2894              100 6.0e-18 
4    35539 GeneScaffold_3680              100 4.6e+00 
5    35540  GeneScaffold_530              100 8.0e-16 
6    35540      contig456880              100 1.3e+00
```

Here is the `dplyr` code

```
newdata <- as.data.frame(group_by(data, Query_id) %>% 
  summarise(
      Subject_id = Subject_id[1], 
      percent_identity = percent_identity[1], 
      evalue = min(evalue))
```

I get this output

```
  Query_id        Subject_id  percent_identity  evalue
1    35538      contig404347           100.00  4.6e+00
2    35539 GeneScaffold_2894           100.00  6.0e-18
3    35540  GeneScaffold_530           100.00  8.0e-16
```

The query id's 3559 and 35540 are ok and according to expected but how about 35538. Even though the evalue are same for both the id's it only selected the first one. Is this the default behaviour of the `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `dplyr` - **you** only "selected the first one".

Recall that `summarize` in `dplyr` returns one row, and **you** decided to return `Subject_id[1]` for the subject ID (even if this does not correspond to the minimum `evalue`!). Likewise, `min(evalue)` returns the (single) minimum `evalue`.

If instead you wish to return all rows that attain the minimum evalue, try

```
data %>%
  group_by(Query_id) %>%
  filter(evalue==min(evalue))
```

which subsets each bit of your dataframe and returns *all* rows with the minimum `evalue`.

Or if you wanted to choose just one row per minimum evalue, you could do

```
data %>% group_by(Query_id) %>% slice(which.min(evalue))
```

which will return the **first** of the rows that attains the minimum (for each `Query_id`), where the first is returned because that is what `which.min` returns (index of the minimum, the first occurring one), and nothing to do with `dplyr`.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my error along with great explanation.